# How to change updated pages on the left navigation pane

Tags: sharepoint-standard

**Using Sharepoint 2013

Does anyone know how to edit the Updated Pages on the left navigation pane? It's right on top of the links. I'd like to have it so I could have all of my pages show up under the Updated Pages and also be able to rename that tab to something like All Pages.

Here's a screenshot of the navigation pane I'm talking about.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the navigation pane I'm talking about.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Updated Pages" links are available only for the Wiki Page Library. SharePoint handles these links internally and by default shows the 5 latest modified Pages in the library.

To change the name of the links from "Updated Pages" to "All Pages", you can use the below javascript:

```
document.querySelector('a[id$=RecentChangesHeaderLink] .menu-item-text').innerText = "All Pages";
```

**EDITED**
To show all pages in PAGES library (not wiki page library) in the left navigation,
go to **Site Settings** => **Navigation (under look and feel)** => check on "**Show Pages**" and click ok.
Now check if the pages appear in the left navigation.
NOTE: These links will be available over the complete site.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will definitely try this. Will this only change the name or the links or will it change the way it works as well? The way updated pages works now, only the 5 most recently updated pages show up and I'd like all of them to show up.

Comment: There is no way to show all pages to show there. if you want to show all pages in the library on the navigation then check the edited parted of the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks very much. I'll have to keep in a wiki page but this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Cog icon (Settings) in the top right --> Site Settings--> Navigation (under the "Look and Feel" section.

You can re-name and re-order

Comment: Ok I see the Quick Launch, but that is for the entire site. The updated pages does not show up on this list. Would I have to make this page (BSA Wiki if you are following the image) a subsite?

Comment: How did you enabled to show these updated pages in quick launch?

Comment: It was default.